# Which is the best method to redirect users from an existing website to an existing WP blog?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website with around 500 HTML pages. I have now posted all these HTML pages into my blog as blog posts. I now want to now redirect users from the page to the blog. I could do that using mod_rewrite or JavaScript?

Since Google will re-index these posts, which of the these two methods would be a better option for SEO?

Kindly also suggest any other techniques you know.

Answer (score 4):

Search engines generally don’t interpret JavaScript. You should better do a proper HTTP redirect. And that can be done with either the [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Here’s a simple example that you can use in your .htaccess file:

```
# mod_alias
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/(.*) /blog/$1

# mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That will redirect requests of the URL path that starts with `/page/` to `/blog/`. So `/page/foo/bar.html` would be redirected to `/blog/foo/bar.html`. Also note the `301` for the proper permanent redirect status code.

Comment: +1. The 301 permanent redirect is the important bit that is needed. There are various ways to do it, but this is as good as any.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it might be easier, but [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) is a WP plugin that handles 301s and logs them.

Answer (score 0):

pop a redirect in your htaccess for the site.